# Limits, derivatives and oscillations

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Suppose, we have a differentiable function $f(x)$ such that
\begin{align*}
0 \le f(x) \le 1
\end{align*}
Let's only look at $0 \le x$.

Also, suppose we have the following two statements

**Statement 1:**

$ \begin{align*}
    \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) =\text{ exists}
    \end{align*}$

**Statement 2:**

There exists $x_0$ such that for all $x\ge x_0$, $f(x)$ is monotonic.

By monotonic I mean non-decreasing or non-increasing. Or in other words, since $f(x)$ is differentiable, $f'(x) \le 0$ or $f'(x) \ge 0$.

So, certainly **Statement 2** implies  **Statement 1** because bounded monotonic functions have limit.

However, **Statement 1** does not imply **Statement 2** one counter example would be  $f(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}$.

My questions are the following

1)  Is the only class of functions, that prevents  **Statement 1** to imply **Statement 2**, is the class for which $f(x)$ has oscillations?

2) What statement (i.e. **Statement 3**) about the derivative of $f(x)$ can I make such that  **Statement 3** and **Statement 1** imply each other in both directions??

Comment: Well...if "oscillating" just means "neither monotonically decreasing nor monotonically increasing" then Yes as to #1, tautologically.  Not sure what you are after in #2.

Comment: My question about 1) is wether $f(x)$ must some how be $f(x)=g(x)*sin(x)$.    In 2) I want the statement like this: $\lim f(x)$ exists iff $f'(x)$ "something".

Comment: @Boby: *any* oscillating function, with bounded amplitude will work, why should it be $\sin(x)$? Here oscillating means just like lulu said, that $f'(x)$ changes sign.

Comment: @Boby  I agree with Alex R., you can't say much in general about how it oscillates.  Suppose, for example, you take something simple like $\frac 1x$ and put in a little bump at 10, then 100, then 1000, and so on.  So long as the bump heights decrease to 0 the limit will be unchanged, but the "oscillations" don't really look sinusoidal or anything.

Comment: I see thank you. Really nice discussion. How about 2)? What can we say about the derivative in order for the limit to exists.

Comment: @Boby  I don't believe any sensible statement about the derivative would imply that the limit exists.  In my "bump" example, I can make the derivative enormous (positive or negative or both).  Some statement of the form "if the derivative has the same sign from some point on AND the function approaches a (finite) limit then the derivative must go to 0" should be true.

Comment: @Boby.  As an exercise, you might want to try to construct a function f(x) such that f'(x) $\rightarrow$ 0 but f(x) does not approach a (finite) limit.  As a harder exercise, try to do it again but also require that f'(x) < 0 for all x.